# Creating dictionaries from large data sets in a spreadsheet or database file

Tags: ios, excel, swift, dictionary, filemaker

Currently the data I want to incorporate into my dictionary is in two fields of an Excel spreadsheet and also in two fields of a database in FileMaker Pro.

Is there an easy way to create a Swift dictionary from this data?

Comment: Do you intend to transfer data only once or repeatedly (every week or similar)? And: which FileMaker version is this? ~Jens

Comment: You can export your Filemaker data to a text file of any format, using XML export in conjunction with a suitable XSLT styleheet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

FileMaker field [calculation, text] =

```
"var dict = [" &
executesql("SELECT keyfield, valuefield FROM table" ;":";"," ) &
"]"
```

produces code to create a swift dictionary of all records of 'table'.

~jens

edit: 'executesql' requires a rather recent FileMaker version, I think 12 or 13.

Comment: i am using version 13 of filemaker.  thank you very much for your helpful advice.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not a swift programmer, just a FileMaker dev, but Jens' answer looks like the best one to me. If you're not familiar with FileMaker Pro, the easiest way to apply that might just be by creating a new GLOBAL field in 'table' and making it a "Calculated" field (make sure to set the result type to Text). Here's a sample file: http://cris.lc/d5zjl

I would add that if you're using FileMaker 11, there are plugins (like BaseElements) that will let you perform SQL queries -- the calculation function would be slightly different, though.

Reply here or PM me if you still need help in FileMaker!

Comment: just wanted to ask if i can somehow only have this calculated field perform the operation once and display in one cell.  at the moment my database has 10,000 rows in two columns so when i apply this code, it gives my back 10,000 dictionaries!  Thanks very much.

Comment: If you make the field a GLOBAL field, then it is actually only calculated once (the same value is used for all 10,000 rows).  However, as you noted, it will show up 10,000 times.

If you only want it once then you could create a new table, make one field in that table (which is the calculated field), and then make one record in that table. ExecuteSQL will work even if FileMaker doesn't see any relationships between the two tables.

Comment: oh wow.  that's really great.  thank you very much for your help.  I managed to do all that and working well.  The only problem that remains for me in my dictionary is displaying quotes for the key and value items when i export to csv file.  I tried using ""/" or """" command but it didn't work as expected.

Comment: I also tried creating two new columns which were the key and value columns with quotes, but when I created the dictionary and exported I was now getting double quotes around the key and value in the dictionary.  I gave up on it after a few hours of trying many different things!  I wonder if this is a limitation of the software for this calculation method or if I am missing something.  Once again thanks for your help.

Comment: If you're willing to send me a copy of your FileMaker file (with a reduced or sample data set, if confidentiality is a concern) then I can take a look at it. You can email me at cristos@cristoslc.com.